# Saving related entities in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't modify existing relations in RoR.
Db schema is users(id), books(id, title), ratings(user_id, book_id, rating)
Models are

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
end
```

Creating new rating with book.ratings.build(:user_id => 1, :rating => 5); book.save works fine, but I can't modify existing rating with

```
r = book.ratings.where(:user_id => 1).first
r.rating = 5
```

book.save doesn't save corresponding rating and r.save raises error about column rating.id. Is there a way to make things work without modifying db schema?

Comment: I think that inside the 'books_controller', in the update action, you have to loop over each 'Rating': '@book.ratings.each do { |r| r.attributes = params[:rating][r.id.to_s] }' for example. Are you trying to do this from a console or from within a method?

Comment: What is the output (in the console) of `book.ratings.where(:user_id => 1).to_sql` and of `r.inspect` ?

Comment: >>b.ratings.where(:user_id => 28).to_sql
"SELECT \"ratings\".* FROM \"ratings\" WHERE (\"ratings\".book_id = 1) AND (\"ratings\".\"user_id\" = 28)">>r = b.ratings.where(:user_id => 28).first
  Rating Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "ratings".* FROM "ratings" WHERE ("ratings".book_id = 1) AND ("ratings"."user_id" = 28) LIMIT 1
#<Rating user_id: 28, book_id: 1, rating: 3, created_at: "2011-01-13 11:12:57", updated_at: "2011-01-13 11:12:57">
>>r.inspect
"#<Rating user_id: 28, book_id: 1, rating: 3, created_at: \"2011-01-13 11:12:57\", updated_at: \"2011-01-13 11:12:57\">"

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting the error is because your ratings table has data but doesn't have and id column.

Add and id column to your ratings table and save your change calling rating.save.

Comment: The question is about keeping db schema as simple as possible. It's classic relation with payload and should be modeled as described in initial post.